# How to send an e-mail without using the MFMailComposeViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, uibutton, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to know if it's possible to send an e-mail automatically by using the uibutton, instead of having to use the MFMailComposeViewController? I basically want to send an e-mail without letting the user edit the recipients address or the subject.

For example, when you press the uibutton it would automatically send these:

```
[mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello@mail.com",nil]];
[mailComposer setSubject:@"Hello there"];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Body" isHTML:NO];
```

Any idea how to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement a [SMTP client](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) in your app.

`MFMailComposeViewController` can't be automated, limited in any way or changed later.

I don't want apps that send spam mails to all my contacts, and apple thought about this too.

Comment: How exactly would I do this? The link you provided doesn't show.

Comment: I have never implemented SMTP, so I can't really help. But I guess `skpsmtpmessage` is no longer maintained (like all those "I upload my code to github/bitbucket/googlecode because I don't have a harddisk for backup" projects *rant*). So you either read the SMTP protocol specification and implement your own client or you search for a not outdated and buggy as hell implementation. You should probably also think again if it's really impossible to use MFMailComposeViewController.